# custom lookup filter using GeoLocation

Tags: apex, lookup, filters

Does anyone have any experience of creating a "roll your own" look-up filter? Essentially i'd like to be able to use the new geoLocation functions to restrict the options available to the user e.g. only show related records that are within 5km.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Lookup filters are not formula based. So unless this changes, I'm not sure it will be feasible. I'm trying to imagine a formula field that you could use in your lookup filter, but getting the current location value into a place accessible to the formula is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As states in my comment, I think you will struggle to find a purely declarative solution to this.

The best I'm coming up with is some custom Visualforce with a Controller extension that dynamically populates a picklist (or some other control) with the possible related records.

Using a controller extension, you could more easily plug into location services to determine current location of the user, giving you the required data to tap into the new SOQL search features for geolocation.